# NGINX + UNICORN + RAILS 4. Assets error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I got problems, with deploy Ruby on Rails application with Nginx and Unicorn.

Application started good, but assets don`t loaded. Can anyone help?

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'mysql2'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'hirb'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"
gem 'russian'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'unicorn'
```

**Nginx conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain-name.ru;
    return 301 $scheme://domain-name.ru$request_uri;
}

upstream unicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.yp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name yellowpump.ru;
    root path_to_app/domain-name.ru/www/public;

    charset utf-8;
    error_page 404 /404.html; 

    location / {
        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @unicorn;
        error_page 404              /404.html;
        error_page 422              /422.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504  /500.html;
        error_page 403              /403.html;
    }

    location @unicorn {
        proxy_pass http://unicorn;
    }

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
            root path_to_app/domain-name.ru/www/public;
            gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
            expires 1y;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header ETag "";
            break;
    }

    #include conf/h5bp.conf;
}
```

**unicorn conf**

```
base_path = "path_to_root_directory_application"

working_directory base_path

pid "#{base_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path "#{base_path}/unicorn/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{base_path}/unicorn/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.yp.sock"
worker_processes 4
timeout 30
```

Unicorn i started `bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -d -E production`

I try to `rake assets:precompile` but got error `marshal data to short`

Can anyone please tell me, what i do wrong??

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompile` server-side? If so, you might try `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` instead

Comment: Thanks! Works! Compiled assets is available, and geting up on assets/application-f1e858d0e003b39637d5d735d8b9d00e.js

Comment: But, in code, assets loading not compiled, how i get this?

Comment: Thanks! All works! I don`t run unicorn on prodaction!